# Как создать массив с локальным временем (HH:MM:SS)?

Tags: c++, c, время

нужно создать символьный массиив с локальны временем(Часы:Минуты:Секунды) 24-часовая система

Comment: В чём конкретно у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: я начинающий,  и на одном сайте увидел как создать такой массив, но тот код выводил время в 12 часовом формате, а как переделать на 24 часовой формат я не знал

Answer (score 7, accepted):

time + localtime + strftime

[Типа](http://ideone.com/7n1Svg)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    time_t t1;
    time(&t1);
    tm * t2 = localtime(&t1);
    char s[40];
    strftime(s,40,"%H:%M:%S",t2);

    puts(s);

}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char buffer[80];
time_t seconds = time(NULL);
tm* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);
char* format = "%H:%M:%S";
strftime(buffer, 80, format, timeinfo);
cout<<"Current Datetime: "<<buffer<<endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}